# Bootstrap is different after deploying to IIS 7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 application, when I tested it locally everything works perfectly. I just published it to an IIS 7 server and when I load it I had two problems 1) An image was not loading, but I fixed that by changing the 'Anonymous Authentication' to the application pool in the Authentication tab of the website in IIS.

The second problem is that there is a difference with bootstrap. Bootstrap is still active but it seems that some of the changes that I made are not working. (BG color is not black, text is not white, page is bigger,..). I included two images at the end to show what I mean.

I checked the files after I published them. Bootstrap.css is updated with my code, in the bundles config it says it uses bootstrap.css and not bootstrap.min.css, so that can't be the problem right?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is how it looks locally when I run it from VS, both times tested with firefox developer edition, same screen, same resolution, same sreenshot size :

[image: local version]

And here is how it looks when it is published on IIS7

[image: IIS7 version]

EDIT: Added image of the console for the network

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console, 404 for example?

Comment: No, before I was getting a 401 from the image not loading but now the console is all good. It also loads the bundles and such. I'll edit in a print screen of that.

Comment: Are you bundling your custmo CSS in with the Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I use the default site.css file and I altered the bootstrap code. They are in the same bundle I think.

Comment: Had the same problem, only solution that I could find was just by copying the bootstrap code into another file created by me...

Comment: @AndreiMaieras yes I fixed the backrgound colour, by making it black in the site.css. But I would rather keep bootstrap in the seperated file. Do you think it would help too just remove the min.css file?

Comment: If I remember well I tried that too, but I think didn't worked

Comment: You could try adding the reference link from bootstrap website into your Layout view and see if the problem is with the file or wrong geting the file when deploying

Comment: Yes but then it is standard bootstrap, the problem is that it isn't showing my alterations to the code of bootstrap. And that the grid is rendered differently.

Comment: I see, why don't you add your css in another file, and overwrite form there whatever you don't want from bootstrap

Comment: It solved the problem with the code that I altered, but the grid is still rendered differently. Any idea as what can cause that ?

Comment: How does it look in your local environment if you try it in release mode?

Comment: The same as the other local one. For some reason when it is in IIS the entire grid seems larger. I have no idea why.

Comment: Looks like body or .container class has a smaller margin on IIS, do you have the same css on the body locally and on IIS?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same CSS, I checked the files.

Comment: Something must be different on the css files, or your window resolution on iis is getting somehow smaller than the local one

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: It just 'went away' with me. Still have no clue what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

I think deleting `bootstrap.min` in your `Content file` should work

Answer (score 0):

If you have altered the **bootstrap.css** file then delete the **bootstrap.min.css** file, reason is because it contains the default values and when the page is being rendered CSS   from that file is also loaded which conflicts and gets you in this problem

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio, Drag and drop the file *.css in the atribute  and is all, The IIS dont find the files *.css like Visual Studio does

Omar Romero

Comment: In the atribute HEAD from the masterpage or the *.aspx

Comment: Is your comment meant to be an edit to your answer?  If it is, you should edit your answer, because it's a bit confusing the way it's worded